# Ошибка str is not callable

Tags: python, строки

Возникла довольно нелепая проблема, пытаюсь прочитать текстовый файл, а оно ругается..

```py
t=mx=0
with open("C:/Users/georg/Downloads/24__dd5.txt", "r") as f:
    s=f.readline()
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s(i)=="X":
            t+=1
        else: mx= t; t = 0
print(mx)
```

Вот что выводит: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш пример обычным текстом, а не картинкой и приведите полный текст ошибки, которую вы получаете.

Comment: Может все же не`s(i)` а `s[i]`?  s это все же не функция на что и ругается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас написано `s(i)`, что воспринимается интерпретатором как вызов функции. Вы скорее всего имели в виду `s[i]`. Т.е. как-то так:

```
t = mx = 0
with open("C:/Users/georg/Downloads/24__dd5.txt", "r") as f:
    s = f.readline()
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == "X":
            t += 1
        else: 
            mx = t
            t = 0
print(mx)
```